# load swc in a js apache royale project

Tags: swc, apache-royale

I have a `.swc` library which I've been using in my flex project. it is a pure .as library compiled into an swc file. So, it does not include any js in it.

here is my `asconfig.json`

```json
// https://github.com/BowlerHatLLC/vscode-as3mxml/wiki/asconfig.json

{
    "config": "royale",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "source-map": true,
        "targets": [
            "JSRoyale"
        ],
        "js-library-path": [
            "libs/MyLibrary.swc"
        ],
        "html-template": "src/resources/template.html",
        "theme": "${royalelib}/themes/JewelTheme/src/main/resources/defaults.css"
    },
    "copySourcePathAssets": true,
    "additionalOptions": "-js-dynamic-access-unknown-members=true",
    "files": [
        "src/MainFlex.mxml"
    ]
}
```

With this setup, the IDE is locating the swc and the auto-completion works and the project compiles but but as soon as I run the project in the browser, the classes in the .swc file won't be recognized and the project fails.

When I look inside the `js-debug` folder, I don't see any js file being generated from my .swc file.

I don't know how I can make sure that the .as code in that swc should be converted into .js code...

Any hint would be appreciated.